# ggplot2 geom_point alpha different in plot to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, point

I have something strange in my plot which I can't figure out. It seems like the transparency of the bubbles in my plot are different to the transparency of those in the legend.

I've found it challenging to provide a reprex for this, so I'm hoping just the code is okay:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = all.shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), 
                                                 color = "grey", size = 0.3,fill = NA) +
      geom_point(data=substation_results, aes(x=Easting, y=Northing, size=factor(Population), 
                                          colour=factor(Population), fill = NA), alpha=0.5) +
      coord_equal() + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral", name = 
      expression('Voltage\nInstability\nZones')) +
      theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), 
      legend.position = "right") +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = FALSE)) + 
      labs(title = "(A) Population Served\nPer Substation") +
      scale_colour_manual(name = "Population\nServed Per\nSubstation\n(Million)",
                  labels = c("<0.15", "0.15-0.3", "0.3-0.45", "0.45-0.6",
                             "0.6-0.75", "0.75-0.9",">0.9"),
                  values = c("skyblue4", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "brown")) +   
      scale_size_manual(name = "Population\nServed Per\nSubstation\n(Million)",
                labels = c("<0.15", "0.15-0.3", "0.3-0.45", "0.45-0.6",
                           "0.6-0.75", "0.75-0.9",">0.9"),
                values = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

This is the image of the plot. You can see the colour of the bubbles and the legend are completely different. Importantly, changing the alpha in geom_point does not change the difference:

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that you have multiple points overplotted at the same location. This would make the points on the map look darker than the legend.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 this solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing duplicate observations using:

```
transformer_node_count <- unique(transformer_node_count)
```

and achieving the desired output:

[image]